# Remove a few items in a cell in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have about 400 cells similar to the following:

```
Headquarters
3 rue Paul Cézanne 
Paris, Ile-de-France    75008
France
Main Phone: 33 1 73 15 11 00
Main Fax: 33 1 73 15 11 24
```

I want to remove items similar to what is shown below from each cell:

```
Main Phone: 33 1 73 15 11 00
Main Fax: 33 1 73 15 11 24
```

In each cell, which contains Main Phone number and Main Fax, only the numerical values are different in each cell (total 400).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the information is kept at cell `A1`.  You can use the following formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Main Phone:", A1),100)
```

It finds the first occurance of the string "Main Phone:" and the `MID` function returns the following 100 characters (or till the end of the cell contents).